# Vim map to delete text inside parenthesis

Tags: vim

I created a map to delete the text inside a parenthesis even if the cursor is outside of the parenthesis. This is the map:

```
nnoremap di( f(,di(
```

I test it with this code:

```c
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
```

The map only works when the cursor is anywhere before `(`. If I place the cursor  after `(` nothing is deleted. Why is the map not working?

Note that try `f(,di(` without defining any map it works (it deletes the text inside the parenthesis regardless of the initial cursor position). Only when I map to `di(`  it does not work.

Comment: Does it work if you type `f(,di(` without the map?

Comment: If I type `f(,di(` without the map it works (it deletes the text inside the parenthesis, regardless of the initial cursor position). But it does not work when I map it to `di(`

Answer (score 1):

I've found a similar question at [vi.stackexchange.com](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14642/key-binding-doesnt-work-as-expected-nnoremap-leadertd-fi-args2esc). The map wasn't working due to behavior documented in `:help map-error`. The solution is to use `:silent!` to prevent the map from aborting on error. The working version of the map is:

```
nnoremap <silent> di( :silent! normal! f(,di(<cr>
```